# Vectorizing batch image pixel lookup numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have an input numpy array of the form `(B, H, W, C)` and have a grid comprised of x values of the form `(B, W)` and y values of the form `(B, H)`.

My goal is to use the x and y values to grab the C values of the image array. I'm able to do it when `B = 1` that is when my image is of the form `(H, W, C)` and when x and y are of the form `(H\W, )` but have no clue how to expand this to a batch of images contained in a single numpy array.

Is there some sort of reshaping I can take advantage of?

**Example**

Suppose I have 2 cat images of size `(400, 400, 3)`. Then `input_img.shape = (2, 400, 400, 3)`.

I have a list `x.shape = (2, 400)` and `y.shape = (2, 400)` and would like to index into `input_img` such that I obtain for each `(x_i, y_i)` an array `z_i.shape = (C, )` totalling `z.shape = (400, C)`.

**What I'm trying to Vectorize**

```
for i in range(batch_size):
    z_i = input_img[i, x[i], y[i]]
```

Comment: Add a sample case?

Comment: @Divakar just added :)

Comment: Could you complete the iterative code? So, I am guessing it would go along these lines : `z_i = input_img[.....]`. I am not sure about that `.....` part, which I am guessing would involve x_i and y_i.

Comment: Got it, I think I made it clearer now @Divakar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
input_img[np.arange(batch_size)[:,None], x, y]
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked but it didn't give the result I expected. I got an output image of shape (2, 400, 3) so I'm missing a dimension (2, 400, 400, 3). Do you have any clue how I could fix the code to evaluate the pixel values for a meshgrid of (x_i y_i)?

Comment: @KevinZakka Try : `input_img[np.arange(batch_size)[:,None,None], x[:,None], y]`?

Comment: Thanks so much! `input_img[np.arange(batch_size)[:,None,None], y0, x0]` did the trick :)